# hda-intel causing crash on dual boot install

Tags: dual-boot, sound

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as dual boot along side Win 7. I have to use nomodeset to progress.

I now get to the 4 loading dots on install but get a hang after a line saying sda-hda-intel error and then it goes to a blank screen.

I have tried disabling high def audio in bios but it does the same thing.

How can I get the install to work?

Thanks

Comment: You made sure to apply the settings in the BIOS, right? Also you probably have already seen this... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto

Comment: Yes I applied the setting in bios. I haven't seen this link before.

Comment: I have tried taking my soundcard out of the mobo, hd audio disabled, and enabled on both settings my bios allows - ac'97 and hdaudio. Is there anyway I can set the boot to skip loading sound drivers through a CLI?

Comment: Please load Ubuntu in safe mode and post the output of this command: `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

Comment: What is the command for entering recovery from the livecd? f4 boot modes does not give a recovery mode option. I can't find the command anywhere. Not doing great on my first question! :)

Comment: Are you booting the live CD in UEFI or legacy mode? Since you are trying to install alongside 7 I'll assume legacy. Right after booting from the DVD when the purple screen appears press the right arrow key and it should give you some options.

Comment: Not sure whether booting in legacy or UEFI. There is no option for that when I load the CD. I press f1 to get to the install menu but will try right arrow now. Thanks.

Comment: Tried pressing right arrow. It brings up the same menu as f1...